# Compiling with FPU on ARM board

Tags: opencv, image-processing, arm, embedded-linux, fpu

I am using mini6410 ARM 1176 board to run image processing application using OpenCV. I am using ARM toolchain 4.5.1 as supplied by the manufacturer of the board with certain options that  may be of interest in this case:

```
--with-cpu=arm1176jzf-s --with-tune=arm1176jzf-s --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=softfp
```

As I create the executable and compile OpenCV using the toolchain and options:

```
-mfloat0-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3
```

Program built successfully. As I run it on the board, I see that the processing time for the program is 25 sec / frame. Which is same with program that is compiled with options:

```
-mfloat-abi=soft
```

I expect the program to run faster with FP usage. Any suggestion where I was wrong? Because OpenCV is compiled with the toolchain and I cannot find any option when creating makefile for OpenCV (I use 2.4.4) that is related to FPU

Comment: Are you sure floating-point ops take non-negligible time in your test-case?

Comment: check the library with objdump and see if it contains vfp instructions.